# Change 'Contact Form' email title in Magento?

Tags: magento

I have a number of Magento stores running from one admin and i receive emails from site users using the online form that appears as 'Contact Form', how can i change this to 'Site 1 Form'.

Answer (score 6):

This can be accomplished without any programming or `.phtml`-template customization:

1. Create a new email template under System -> Transactional emails, load the Contact Form template.
2. Change the title to `{{config path="general/store_information/name"}} Contact Form`
3. Make sure you have a store name configured for each store under System -> Configuration -> General -> Store Information -> Store Name

Comment: And change it to something non-spammy. "Contact Us" seemed to be a spam filter magnet on our website, changing it around to be worded **"Company Name" Customer Service** or a variant thereon keeps it out of our rep's spam folder. As Alex points out, always use Magento's built-in capabilities where you can and save the template customizations for things that really need it. You'll have less headaches on version upgrades then.